# Java EE - creating a register-by-email setup

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

Assuming I have a web app (Java EE 6), I want to realize the following use case:

1. On a generic "register" page, user enters his/her email and submits
2. System sends email to user. In this mail, there should be a link to a full registration page
3. User follows link, fills out required credentials, and submits
4. System stores user in database, and sends confirmation email
5. All temporary data is discarded.

The part I am having problems with is mostly step 2. What I need to know is the following:

1. What is the best way of setting up a personal registration page for the user? Should I generate a temporary page and link to it? Should I give the user a special cookie? In either case, how can I implement this? No code is needed, I just need some pointers on where to start looking and coding.

EDIT:

A very important question here, no matter how I do it, is the following: How can I generate and deploy a temporary webpage? I am rather new to Java EE, so forgive me if this has an obvious answer.

Comment: well, unless you have to use JEE (e.g. work) then try Ruby on Rails, Django or Node.js, I'm sure you'll find much more examples that do exactly that already on github

Comment: See this question 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3038930/user-sign-up-with-email-verification

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the registration page is standard for every user then there is no need in creating a temporary page and linking to it or creating a special cookie etc...  Just create the page with the registration form on it and send your clients a link to that.

If you want a special customized registration page for a specific user, then you can just send an e-mail with a link to your client with their information as a query parameter (ie http://yoursite.com/registration?fname=jordan&lname=denison) or you could use something like [PrettyFaces](http://ocpsoft.org/prettyfaces/) to make the URL more readable as well as making it easier to extract those parameters and fire a method with them.

Comment: Thanks, your second suggestion is closer to what I want to achieve, but I realize my skills fall short here, and I am not entirely sure how to work with parameters. I get the overall procedure though, and the PrettyFaces project looks very interesting, thanks for pointing to it, I will check it out.

Answer (score 1):

If I had to do it, then I would have

1. Created a generic registration page
2. Created a unique ID for the user
3. Send the link to user which contains the unique ID as a parameter
4. The registration page throws error if the unique ID is not presented to it, or the ID is not valid (already used, or not issued)